# Autodesk - Get manifest info with Javascript

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there an easy accessible function to get manifest data in javascript to check if the model is done translating?

something like `viewerApp.getManifest().progress`. Where `viewerApp` is a ViewingApplication.

Is there something like this, or should I retrieve the data via server code and pass it on to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not an client side API as you mentioned to get the progress of model translation.

I am interested in the reason why doing that way. Actually, the ViewingApplication is a client side API and is used to view the model when the model is already translated, it's not suggested to request the translation progress by this API.

If you want to get the status of the translation progress, Yes, using the [GET :urn/Manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) to get the progress.

Comment: Ah okay! Well I wanted to show the progress of the model and was wondering if the manifest information was already received when the model gets loaded (or tries to load) in the viewer. I will then make the request from server side or javascript to get the manifest info. Thanks!